# Is there any backwards-compatible alternative to RegSetKeyValueA function?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, backwards-compatibility

In my application, I use [RegSetKeyValueA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluea) to store some activation keys in the registry.

The only bottleneck that stops my app from being backwards-compatible with windows XP is [RegSetKeyValueA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluea) function.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: `RegSetValueExA` that is listed next to subj function

Comment: In this day and age, dropping XP support may be the better option.

Comment: @VTT what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that using `RegSetValueExA` would be a way around...

Comment: yes, `RegSetValueExW` - use *W* api version always better compare *A*

Comment: @VTT That's right! It's working! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [RegSetValueExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa)

It is very easy to confuse the two due to similar very similar signature.

[RegSetValueExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa)

> Minimum supported client   Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only]

[RegSetKeyValueA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluea)

> Minimum supported client   Windows Vista [desktop apps only]

Answer (score 2):

the [`RegSetKeyValueW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluew) functional can be easy implemented by use [`RegSetValueExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexw) which is exist from Windows 2000

```
LSTATUS MyRegSetKeyValueW(
                        HKEY    hKey,
                        LPCWSTR lpSubKey,
                        LPCWSTR lpValueName,
                        DWORD   dwType,
                        LPCVOID lpData,
                        DWORD   cbData
                        )
{
    LSTATUS s;

    if (lpSubKey && *lpSubKey)
    {
        s = RegCreateKeyExW(hKey, lpSubKey, 0, 0, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, 0, &hKey, 0);

        if (s != NOERROR)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

    s = RegSetValueExW(hKey, lpValueName, 0, dwType, 
        static_cast<PBYTE>(const_cast<void*>(lpData)), cbData);

    if (lpSubKey && *lpSubKey)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return s;
}
```

and replace in self code `RegSetKeyValueW` to `MyRegSetKeyValueW`. possible do the same with *A* version, but need understand that *A* version convert string parameters to unicode and then call *W* version. so always better direct call *W* version

Answer (score 0):

Use [SHSetValueA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shsetvaluea) (shlwapi.lib), it works all the way back to IE4 (Win98,2000+).

If you are setting many values you should use `RegCreateKeyA` to create the key and call `SHSetValueA` will NULL as the subkey.